# WebSQL update isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, web-sql

today i was helping a friend with a solution and in the runtime the UPDATE in my PC works and in his pc doesn't . we've checked the databases and they are all Okay, i tried to upload the code to my raspberry pi and it doesn't work. we've tried to debug the code, and it went straight to the callBack function (it didn't gave error).
The databese is based in WebSQL and the code is this one:

```
$('#save').click(function(){
      var db=openDatabase('ATS_db2', '1.0', 'base de dados ATS', 2*2048*2048);
      db.transaction(function (tx){
        var nome =$('#alteranome').val();
        var bi =$('#alterabi').val();
        var nif =$('#alteranif').val();
        var morada=$('#alteramorada').val();
        var contatos = $('#alteracontatos').val();
        var id = $('#Id_cliente').val();
      tx.executeSql('UPDATE Cliente Set Nome=? ,Bi=? ,Nif=? ,Morada=? ,Contatos=?  where Id_cliente = ?;',[nome,bi,nif,morada,contatos,id],function(tx,results){
        alert("Cliente alterado com sucesso");
        //location.reload();
      },errorHandler);
});
    });
errorHandler = function (transaction, error) {
  // returns true to rollback the transaction
  debugger;
  alert("Error processing SQL: "+ error);
  return true; 
}
```

Can someone know what is happening?
Ty ;)

Comment: When you uploaded the code to your Raspberry Pi, it stopped working on your PC too? WebSQL runs on client side, please post the browser version you and your friend are using. Also, you tagged `Cordova` in your question, is it relevant?

Comment: i tagged the cordova too , because the final project should be an APK. but this isn't the problem right now. I'm using the raspberry to host the files remotly. 
If i use the code in my local machine, the update works, when i access to the rasp, it doesn't. the version of my Browser is:
Chrome 36.0.1985.143 m